# where is application/others in ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, lamp, xampp

First, im new in ubuntu so please bear with me.

I've installed xampp for linux (lampp), and now im trying to get its UI (like windows) by following this [guide](http://freshtutorial.com/add-gui-xampp-control-panel-ubuntu/)

I've successfully followed the guide, until the final step that i must open the xampp in Application>>> Others.

**Where is this application/others folder?** I tried to find it and do some googling but i still cant find it.

Thanks for your time :D

Comment: You can find all applications in folder `/usr/share/applications` Actually it contains all the short-cuts that have been installed. Probably you'll find your `Xampp` short-cut there. Browse `/usr/share/applications` path using any `file manager`.

Comment: @SauravKumar Thanks for your help. Theres no "Others" folder or "XAMPP" in my /usr/share/applications. I think the xampp is correctly installed because i can access it by typing "localhost" in my browser.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you use the `dash` to find the application so hit the windows key and start typing `xampp-control-panel` and somewhere around character 3 or 4 it should show you the program you need to start.

As a fallback you can use the command line. Your desktop file tells you this:

```
Exec=gksudo python /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py
```

So you can do ...

```
gksudo python /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py
```

on command line and get it to activate.

Besides that: if you start the xampp control panel it will also add an icon to the Unity Launcher. That negates most of the guide you are using (that guide is from 2010 so not really suited for a 2013 release).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried form the terminal and it returns an error : Error importing pygtk2 and pygtk2-libglade. What should i do? Can i just find the program and run it? (without using terminal)